# Beanstalkd - tube X is Y seconds old

Tags: beanstalkd

Beanstalkd is logging this message in error log. I can't find any useful information about this message.

What does it mean, should we worry about it?

Answer (score 0):

I've just looked at the [Beanstalkd source code](https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd) and there doesn't appear to be any such message there. Are you running some kind of customised version?

Comment: I'm not sure. This is what I've got from sysadmin. I guess that they're using non customized version. Yet they have some monitoring stuff, maybe it's responsible for message.

I'll talk to them and get some more feedback. Thanks for info!

Comment: Yup it's not beanstalkd, it's monitoring software. I'm closing it.